# Android create item in GridView with round corners and ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, rounded-corners, cardlayout

I have a GriView in which every element is a card with rounded corners. At the top of it there's an ImageView loaded from the net. I would like to fit the image inside the card so that it will have the top corners rounded. I've tryied with layer-list background, but no result.

[image: Here is an image to show what I want.]

Is there anyone who can give me some hints?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution: just put a rounded imageview (rectangle with rounded corners) behind the opaque relative layout (with same amount of rounded corners only in the bottom) and then set a negative bottom margin in the imageview, so that it will be covered for nearly 5 px by the relative layout

Answer (score 1):

you can use this [lib](https://github.com/pungrue26/SelectableRoundedImageView)

and set this parameter for it:

```
<com.joooonho.SelectableRoundedImageView
    ...
    app:sriv_left_top_corner_radius="16dip"
    app:sriv_right_top_corner_radius="16dip"
    app:sriv_left_bottom_corner_radius="0dip"
    app:sriv_right_bottom_corner_radius="0dip"
    ...
    app:sriv_oval="false" />
```